# Multiple coins on one server running MPOS/stratum

Tags: stratum

I've got an instance of MPOS and a stratum server running a single PeerCoin pool perfectly fine.

How do I go about adding a second pool to the same server?

I've tried to duplicate both the stratum server folders and the MPOS folders, then configure for a different coin. However, when when I browse to the other MPOS instance, for example `www.mysite.com/MPOSSECONDSITE/public`, it loads a blank page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the second stratum server work?

Comment: yes, it works great actually.  I'm just trying to add a second coin pool

Answer (score 1):

Have you given proper permission to

```
www.mysite.com/MPOSSECONDSITE/public
```

If not, use this:

```
cd /home/username/mpos chown -R www-data templates/compile templates/cache logs
```